# Docker Compose file to Docker Stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have found an awesome repo that uses docker-compose however I would like to use it Docker Cloud Stacks (I am a newbie).

What would I have to do to be able to swap it over?

**docker-compose:**

```
version: "2"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:10.2-3.0.2
  php:
# 1. Images with vanilla WordPress – wodby/wordpress:[WP_VERSION]-[PHP_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
    image: wodby/wordpress:4-7.2-3.3.1

    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      PHP_FPM_CLEAR_ENV: "no"
    volumes:
      - codebase:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    image: wodby/wordpress-nginx:4-1.13-3.0.2
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_CONTENT_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
    volumes:
      - codebase:/var/www/html

    depends_on:
      - php
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=nginx'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:wp.docker.localhost'

  varnish:
   image: wodby/wordpress-varnish:4.1-2.3.1
   depends_on:
      - nginx
   environment:
       VARNISH_SECRET: secret
       VARNISH_BACKEND_HOST: nginx
       VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT: 80
  labels:
       - 'traefik.backend=varnish'
       - 'traefik.port=6081'
       - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:varnish.wp.docker.localhost'

  redis:
    image: wodby/redis:4.0-2.1.4


  blackfire:
     image: blackfire/blackfire
     environment:
       BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID: 
       BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN:


  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=mailhog'
      - 'traefik.port=8025'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.wp.docker.localhost'

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=portainer'
      - 'traefik.port=9000'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.wp.docker.localhost'

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
#      - '8080:8080' # Dashboard
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
  codebase:
```